# Pointer declaration doubts

Tags: c, pointers

I'm doing this code to represent a 2d array `T[i][j]`, which I want to get the values and make iterations with them.
So, first I declared `T = {0}`, these are my initial values of the matrix, then the `if`s go completing the matrix.
After that, the `a` changes, and renew the values of the matrix, this is why I'm using pointers, to get the new values, instead of the initial value of `T`, as a whole 0 array.
But the problem is that, I'm getting the same results with all matrices printed.

I think the problem is in this declaration:

`float T[3][3] = {0}; float (*pT)[3] = T;`

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    float Z = 0.2;
    float R = 0.03;
    float ra = 0.01;

    float ks = 1.0;
    float ke = 1.0;
    float kw = 1.0;
    float kn = 1.0;

    float ro = 1.0;
    float c = 1.0;
    float w = 1.0;
    float Ta = 1.0;
    float gm = 1846.35;

    int nr = 3; /* valores de nr apenas multiplos de 3*/
    int nz = 3;

    int i, j, a;

    float T[3][3] = {0};
    float (*pT)[3] = T;

    for (a = 0; a < (10*10*10*10); a++){

    float vetorq [nz];

    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++){

        float h = 1;
        float b = 1;
        float c = nz/10;
        vetorq [i] = (h * exp(- (nz - b)*(nz - b)/ 2*c*c));

        for (j = 0; j < nz; j++){

            float an = (((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra) * kn * ((R - ra)/nr) * nz)/ Z;
            float ae = (((i + 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr) + ra) * ke / nz * nr) / (R - ra);
            float aw = (((i + 1.0) * ((R - ra)/ nr) + ra) * kw * Z / nz * nr)/ (R - ra);
            float asul = (((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra) * ks * ((R - ra)/nr) * nz)/ Z;
            float ap = an + ae + aw + asul + (ro * c * w);
            float aef = 0;

            if (i == 0 && j == 0){
                *(*(T + i) + j) = an * ((*(*(T + i) + j + 1)) / ap) + ae * ((*(*(T + i + 1) + j)) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}

            else if(i != 0 && i != nr - 1.0 && j == 0){
                    *(*(T + i) + j) = ae * ((*(*(T + i + 1) + j)) / ap) + aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}

            else if(i == nr - 1 && j == 0){
                aef = ((((i + 2.0) * (R - ra)/ nr) + ra) * Z * vetorq[i] / nz);
               *(*(T + i) + j) = an * ((*(*(T + i) + (j + 1))) / ap) + aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


            else if(i != nr - 1 && j != 0 && j != nz - 1){
                aef = ((((i + 2.0) * (R - ra)/ nr) + ra) * Z * vetorq[i] / nz);
                *(*(T + i) + j) = asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + an * ((*(*(T + i) + (j + 1))) / ap) + aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}

            else if(i == nr - 1 && j == nz - 1){
                aef = ((((i + 2.0) * (R - ra)/ nr) + ra) * Z * vetorq[i] / nz);
                *(*(T + i) + j) = aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


            else if(i != nr - 1 && i != 0 && j == nz - 1){
                *(*(T + i) + j) = aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + ae * (*(*(T + i + 1) + j) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


            else if(i == 0 && j == nz - 1){
                *(*(T + i) + j) = ae * ((*(*(T + i + 1) + j)) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


            else if(i == 0 && j != nz - 1 && j == 0){
                *(*(T + i) + j) = ae * ((*(*(T + i + 1) + j)) / ap) + an * ((*(*(T + i) + (j + 1))) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


            else (i != 0 && i != nr - 1 && j != 0 && j!= nz - 1);{
                *(*(T + i) + j) = ae * ((*(*(T + i + 1) + j)) / ap) + aw * ((*(*(T + i - 1) + j)) / ap) + an * ((*(*(T + i) + (j + 1))) / ap) + asul * ((*(*(T + i) + (j - 1))) / ap) + ((gm * Z/ nz * ((i + (1.0 / 2.0) * ((R - ra)/nr)) + ra)) * (R - ra)/ nr) + (ro * c * w * Ta) + (aef / ap);}


             printf("%d  ", *(*(T + i) + j));

             }
         printf("\n  \n ");

        }

printf("\n \n \n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: These variable names are infuriatingly opaque. Adding some functions here to explain what's going on would help considerably with understanding, and would give the code a more easily understood structure.

Comment: Stop using `*(*(T + i) + j) ` and just say `T[i][j]` It does the same thing but makes way more sense.

Comment: After reading and re-reading your question I'm still perplexed as to why pointers are necessary here. You don't even use the pointer you're grumbling about.

Comment: `float (*pT)[3] = T;` declares a variable that is never used. You should remove that line.

Comment: Ok, considering with no pointers and with all `*(*(T + i) + j)` as `T[i][j]`. The code still prints the same matrices. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on warnings in your compiler. In GCC or Clang, add `-Wall -Werror` to the command-line switches. Pay attention the warning and error messages and fix them before proceeding.

Second, Clang says:

```
y.c:87:51: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
            else (i != 0 && i != nr - 1 && j != 0 && j!= nz - 1);{
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
```

An `else` clause does not take a condition. It gives a statement to be executed when all the **other** tests before it have failed. If you want the statements in braces to be executed when those other tests have failed, then remove the conditions in parentheses and the semicolon:

```
            else {
```

If you want the statements to be executed only when the other tests have failed **and** the conditions you have here are true, then change `else` to `else if` and remove the semicolon:

```
            else if (i != 0 && i != nr - 1 && j != 0 && j!= nz - 1) {
```

Third, Clang says:

```
y.c:91:29: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'float' [-Wformat]
             printf("%d  ", *(*(T + i) + j));
                     ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     %f
```

`%d` is for `int`. The elements within `T` have type `float`. `%f` is for `float` (or `%e` or `%g`). Change this to:

```
             printf("%f  ", *(*(T + i) + j));
```

Fourth, stop using `*(*(T + i) + j))`. Use `T[i][j]`, and `T[i+1][j]`, `T[i][j+1]`, and so on. Although they are equivalent to the compiler, the latter is much more readable.

Comment: I see, the first and the second tips I didn't know. But the third I was doing just like you said, but it was printing the same matrices inside the for loop with the variable a, so I was trying to use the pointers to solve that problem. I made the changes again now with what you said, but it keeps printing the same matrices, and with -1.#Qnano in 8 places of the matrix. Do you know why?